# Seeding tenant database in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration, laravel-artisan

I am working on building a system using a main database and multiple tenant databases in laravel 5. I have a database migration and seed for the main database no problem, using `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`.

Tenants then get their own database upon registration. I need to run a migration and seed on the tenants database.

The tenant migration files are stored in a separate folder. The migration runs (unfortunately on the main database) with the following command

```
\Artisan::call('migrate', [
        '--path'     => "database/migrations_system"
       );
```

However I need the migration to occur on the tenant database, say DB_1.

I read the following should work

```
\Artisan::call('migrate', [
    '--path'     => "database/migrations_system",
    '--database' => 'db_1'
    ]);
```

However I end up with an error

```
InvalidArgumentException in DatabaseManager.php line 238:
```

Database [db_1] not configured.

Stuck.... How can I specify the migration to run on a specific database?

UPDATE:

I have found that changing `config/database.php` and adding db_1 gets me past this error....

```
'db_1' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => 'db_1',
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'port' => '3306'
        ],
```

However this connection is unknown and needs to be done on the fly, which I am also stuck on how to accomplish....

UPDATE Again and working solution.... Modify the config on the fly...

```
 $connections = \Config::get('database.connections');
        $tenant_database = 'db_1'; //assign from your main database
        $tenant_connection = [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => $tenant_database ,
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'port' => '3306'
        ];
        $connections['tenant'] = $tenant_connection;
        \Config::set('database.connections', $connections);
       \Artisan::call('migrate', [
        '--path'     => "database/migrations_system",
        '--database' => 'tenant'
        ]);
```

So it looks like I have answered my own question, however maybe some can comment on this procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put my own solution down.... 
1) Create the database name
For example I name the new database `db_1` where 1 represents the ID of the system in the main database. I have considered storing a unique scrambled name in the main database. In the end that seemed like overkill.

2) Create the connection - for this I use the exact same name as the new database.

```
public function createConnection()
{
    $connections = \Config::get('database.connections');

    if(!isset($connections[$this->getSystemName()]))
    {

        $tenant_connection = [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => $this->getSystemName(),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'port' => '3306'
        ];

        $connections[$this->getSystemName()] = $tenant_connection;

        \Config::set('database.connections', $connections);
        //dd(\Config::get('database.connections'));
    }
}
```

3) Create the database, which you do using your main connection

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE " . $this->tenant_name; 
DB::connection('main_db')->statement($sql);
```

4)run the migration

```
$r = \Artisan::call('migrate', [
                '--path'     => "database/migrations_tenant",
                '--database' => $this->tenant_name
            ]);
```

5) finally you can seed test data or load some default data. Access the connection like

```
DB::connection($this->system_name)->table($table)->insert($csv);
```